# Is there a difference between Close Cubic Packing and Face Centered Packing?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, terminology, materials

I see some places use close cubic packing (ccp) and face centered packing (fcp) interchangeably. Are they the same thing? Does one provide more information than the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry for "[Cubic crystal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system)" says:

> ...Face-centered cubic (abbreviated cF[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system) or fcc, and alternatively
> called cubic close-packed or ccp)

In [another entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres) it is stated:

> ...face-centered cubic (fcc) (also called cubic close packed)...

The text of the above references make no statement about one term providing any more or less information than the other.  This does not preclude the possibility that some organization or another may have a preference for one term or the other, but the meaning seems to be the same.

Comment: No need for the *seems to* and other decertainisers; they are ;)

Answer (score 1):

Typically close-cubic packing refers to the high packing factor of FCC systems. It can be used interchangeably with FCC but usually used with metallic materials only, where the atoms are all the same.

Face-centered cubic is used for metals and other materials as it describes the Barvis lattice of a material, which an FCC packing may not yield the highest packing factor in a non-metallic material.